# why "this.seats" become "undefined"? (you can look this in JSBin)

Tags: knockout.js, haxe

I am learning Haxe and KnockoutJS, but this simple code doesn't work(you can look this in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qigis/1/)). I cannot remove member in the page.

**index.html**

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>name</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Main.hx**

```
package ;

import js.Lib;
import knockout.*;

class Main {

    static function main() {
        Knockout.applyBindings(new MemberViewModel());
    }

}

class MemberViewModel {

    public var seats : Dynamic;

    public function new() {
        this.seats = Knockout.observableArray([
            {name: "Steve"}, 
            {name: "Bert"}
        ]);
    }

    public function removeSeat(seat) : Void {
        trace(this.seats);
        this.seats.remove(seat);
    }

}
```

I cannot understand the reason why `this.seats` become `undefined`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: because the context of the function is the seat you clicked on, so if you click remove on Steve `this` refers to the object `{name: "Steve"}`

Comment: In **Haxe**, `this` always refers to the class. I tried to change `this` e.x. `var self = this;` but the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are losing context, use ***[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)*** to make the context to be the class

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat.bind($root)">Remove</a>
```

***[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pevexujo/1/edit)***

You lose context when a method is passed as an argument or set to a variable and then invoked. This example will show what I mean better

```
function someObject(){}
someObject.prototype.someMethod = function(){
   console.log("Context: ",this);
}

var newObj = new someObject();
newObj.someMethod();
//Console will show: Context:  someObject {someMethod: function}
var methodVar = newObj.someMethod;
methodVar();
//Console will show: Context:  Window {...}
function fnCall(method){
   method();
}
fnCall(newObj.someMethod);
//Console will show: Context:  Window {...}
```

Using bind lets you set the context

```
fnCall(newObj.someMethod.bind(newObj));
//Console will show: Context:  someObject {someMethod: function}
```